# Mandar correos PHP , Servidor GoDaddy

Tags: php, html

Estimados , recientemente compre un dominio y `hosting` en `GoDaddy`, todo bien hasta que me cree mi formulario con mi archivo .`php` para que me lleguen los correos a mi correo electrónico, por lo que me encuentro que no me llega nada , aquí mi código

PHP

```
    <?php
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$empresa = $_POST['mensaje'];

$header = 'From: ' . $mail . " \r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

$mensaje = "Este mensaje fue enviado por " . $nombre . ",\r\n";
$mensaje .= "Su e-mail es: " . $mail . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST['mensaje'] . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y', time());

$para = '***@****.com';
$asunto = 'Mensaje de mi sitio web';

mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje), $header);

header("Location:index.html");
?>
```

Aquí mi `form`

```
<form action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm"  action="process.php">
                <div class="col-md-6 padding-right-zero">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Su Nombre" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                        <div class="validation"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Su Correo" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                        <div class="validation"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Asunto" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                        <div class="validation"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
                        <div class="validation"></div>
                    </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit">ENVIAR</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Y bueno no me doy cuenta si mi código esta mal la verdad me parece que esta correcto aparte de que lo utilice una ves en otra pagina pero en otro servidor y si funcionaba , alguien sabe si `GoDaddy` tiene alguna configuración mas que no sepa , soy bastante nuevo en todo esto. Agradezco toda ayuda gracias

Comment: Intenta ponerte en contacto con el [soporte de `GoDaddy`](https://ar.godaddy.com/contact-us.aspx?ci=), por lo que he visto un error común es que el `MX entry` suele estar mal configurado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función mail() devuelve true si el correo fue enviado o false si no se pudo enviar.

```
if(mail(/* parámetros /*)) {
    // El correo fue enviado correctamente
} else {
    // No se pudo enviar el correo
    // Es necesario contactar con el soporte de tu hosting
}
```

Por lo general, cuando el correo se envía y no lo recibes en servicios como gmail, hotmail, yahoo, etc., es porque los encabezados son insuficientes y se marcará como SPAM; en algunos casos llegará a la bandeja de elementos no deseados, pero también puede que nunca lo recibas.

Sugerencia: Usa una librería como **[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)** que genera encabezados muy completos y reduces al mínimo la posibilidad de que los correos sean considerados como SPAM.